# SharePoint Online: Drop down list Language Selection

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to create a drop down list which lets you select your language for the whole of a sharepoint communication site?

Or a new site page that lets you select your language?

It would be great if I could just add a dropdown to my homepage with all languages and users can click it to translate the whole site

Thank you